# Can you convert this example of Security.Authenticator to scala?

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework-2.0

This is an example of authentication implementation in Play:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;

import models.*;

public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        return ctx.session().get("email");
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {
        return redirect(routes.Application.login());
    }
}
```

But this is in Java and I need to convert it to Scala. This is what I tried but it does not work. It is not able to find the redirect method.

```
package controllers

import play.mvc.Security
import play.mvc.Http.Context
import play.mvc.Result
import play.mvc.Results.Redirect

class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

  override def getUsername(ctx: Context) : String = {
    "username_placeholder"
  }

  override def onUnauthorized(ctx: Context) : Result = {
    // Cannot find reference to redirect!
    redirect(routes.Application.index())
  }

}
```

redirect is actually a static method in one of the super class. So I tried to create a companion object for Secured with onUnauthorized def. But that to did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call redirect as if the class where `redirect` resides were an object: `play.mvc.Results.redirect(...)` (assuming you are not looking for any other possible overload somewhere else.)